# Do you know what this connector is called?

Tags: rf, connector, identification

It connects a GPS antenna to the PCB with the receiver and other components. The device was accidentally dropped, and this connector seems to have been damaged because it doesn't mate properly with the receptacle anymore. Is it possible to cut it off and replace?

Cheers!

[image: mystery connector]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the connector it mates to?

Comment: Looks like an SMB (female) connector that has the male end stuck inside of it, but I can't be certain that it's not proprietary without a better picture as well as the mating side of the connection.

Comment: Try to pull out the white part, then take another photo of the end, and try to get more light in the photo (including the background) for a better exposure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a broken MMCX male connector to me. These are popular antenna connectors for embedded GPS receivers.
[image: MMCX right angle]

As the comments mention, it would be useful to have a photo of the mating socket to be sure.

Yes, you can purchase replacement connectors to be soldered + crimped onto the existing cable. But they're very fiddly. I would be inclined to either just buy a new antenna complete with connectorized pigtail, or cut the existing cable and crimp on an SMA plug to use with a short SMA to MMCX adapter cable, which are readily available.

Answer (score 1):

As others already mention about confusion of proper connection and connectors in picture due to angle and details, there are possibility of having both male and female connectors stack together in supplied image.

Although definite identification can't be done, it is really possible to find something to replace your damage connection. From picture it seems connectors on cable is not damage but possibly the part fixed on board took the hits. In such case you need to identify the spot on board it was attached.

To repair board you have to take special care for both soldering work and removing embedded parts from connectors with cable side.